# How to apply transition only defined element, not its child? // simple accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I am in a sitiation which i need to use transition on `li`'s width but not its child `img`

There is small images in `li` element. When user hover's `li` element `width` is expanding with inside image.

I am trying to expand image with **no** `transition` but its parent `li` need expand with `transition`.

[Here is jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/590/)

**css:**

```
ul.images { position:fixed; top:0px;left:0px; width:2660px; }
  ul.images li { 
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding:10px;
    width:50px; 
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul.images li img { 
    float:left; width:100%; height: auto;

 /* this doesn't work */
-webkit-transition: all 0s;
   -moz-transition: all 0s;
     -o-transition: all 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0s;
        transition: all 0s;
}
ul.images li.active { float:left; width: 270px; }
ul.images li.active img { height: 100%; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('ul.images li').first().addClass('active');
$('ul.images li').bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('ul.images li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove the rule `ul.images li.active img { height: 100%; }` and try

Comment: @ArunPJohny still happening bro, also values must like this. Its like a **css bug** why transition applies to the child element automaticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting a fixed `width` for the image in `px` rather than `%`. As the `%` will adopt to the container.

```
ul.images { position:fixed; top:0px;left:0px; width:2660px; }
ul.images li { 
    float:left;
    margin-right:1px;
    background: red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 500px;
    padding:10px;
    width:50px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
}

ul.images li img { 
    float:left; width:50px; height: auto;
}
ul.images li.active { float:left; width: 270px; }
ul.images li.active img { width:270px; height: 100%; }
```

and adding `overflow;hidden` on the `li`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/591/)

I hope I understood you right. Good luck!